# SQLITE_ERROR SQL error or missing database (near "Statements": syntax error)

Tags: java, sqlite, intellij-idea

I am trying to apply injection attack prevention by using prepared statements. The way my code is set up is that I have a DBManager classe which acts as the catalyst between Java and sqlite by storing the java methods responsible for executing sqlite statements. Then I have table classes which store the sqlite statements themselves. Basically, I want to store a prepared statement which executes an INSERT statement and have a connection to it when  I call an open() method. Here are excerpts from the two classes in question where I am trying to create a prepared stament for a constant stored in the IncomeStatementTable class:

```
package com.anniemals.database;

//the database package is meant to be the API package which
// takes all queried values from a database and sets them to values
// in each respective class

//MAKE SURE TO ADD METHODS TO ACCESS DB METADATA, FUNCTIONS, AND VIEWS LATER!
import com.anniemals.clients.ClientInfoIncomeStatement;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DBManager {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "clients.db";
    public static final String DB_PATH = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Steven/Documents/ProjectAnnieMalsRemote/Databases/" + DB_NAME;

    //SortOrders for queries
    public static final int ORDER_BY_NONE = 1;
    public static final int ORDER_BY_ASC = 2;
    public static final int ORDER_BY_DESC = 3;

    //Sets a connection to access and utilize sqlite expressions, which are assigned to the PreparedStatement variables for later use
    private Connection conn;

//Inserts
    private PreparedStatement insertIntoIncomeStatementPStatement;
//Composition has-a relationships for Table Classes
    private ClientInfoTable clientInfoTable;
    private IncomeStatementTable incomeStatementTable;

    public DBManager() {
        //Composition has-a relationships for Table Classes
        this.clientInfoTable = new ClientInfoTable();
        this.incomeStatementTable = new IncomeStatementTable();
    }

    public static DBManager getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    //Open and Close DB methods

    public boolean open(){
        try{
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_PATH);
//STATEMENT WHICH CAUSED THE ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            insertIntoIncomeStatementPStatement = conn.prepareStatement(incomeStatementTable.getInsertIncomeStatement());
            System.out.println("Database Opened");
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Couldn't connect to database: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void close(){
        try {
            if (insertIntoIncomeStatementPStatement != null){
                insertIntoIncomeStatementPStatement.close();
            }
            if(insertIntoClientInfoPStatement != null){
                insertIntoClientInfoPStatement.close();
            }
            if (conn != null){
                conn.close();
                System.out.println("Database closed");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Couldn't close connection: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


public class IncomeStatementTable {

    //Column Labels
    public static final String TABLE_INCOME = "Income Statements";
    public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_CLIENT_ID = "Client ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_DATE = "Date";
    public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_TOTAL_OPER_EXPENSES = "Total Operating Expenses";
    public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_GROSS_PROFIT = "Gross Profit";
    public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_AMORTIZATION = "Amortization";
    public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_EBITDA = "E.B.I.T.D.A.";
    public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_PROFIT_BEFORE_TAX = "Profit Before Tax";
    public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_TAX = "Tax";
    public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_NET_PROFIT = "Net Profit";
    public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_EARN_PER_SHARE = "Earnings Per Share";

    //Column Indexes
    public static final int INDEX_INCOME_ID = 1;
    public static final int INDEX_INCOME_CLIENT_ID = 2;
    public static final int INDEX_INCOME_DATE = 3;
    public static final int INDEX_INCOME_TOTAL_OPER_EXPENSES = 4;
    public static final int INDEX_INCOME_GROSS_PROFIT = 5;
    public static final int INDEX_INCOME_AMORTIZATION = 6;
    public static final int INDEX_INCOME_EBITDA = 7;
    public static final int INDEX_INCOME_PROFIT_BEFORE_TAX = 8;
    public static final int INDEX_INCOME_TAX = 9;
    public static final int INDEX_INCOME_NET_PROFIT = 10;
    public static final int INDEX_INCOME_EARN_PER_SHARE = 11;

public static final String INSERT_INCOME_STATEMENT = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_INCOME + "(" + COLUMN_INCOME_ID +
            ", " + COLUMN_CLIENT_ID +  ", " + COLUMN_INCOME_DATE  + ", " + COLUMN_INCOME_TOTAL_OPER_EXPENSES
            + ", " + COLUMN_INCOME_GROSS_PROFIT  + ", " + COLUMN_INCOME_AMORTIZATION  + ", " + COLUMN_INCOME_EBITDA
            + ", " + COLUMN_INCOME_PROFIT_BEFORE_TAX  + ", " + COLUMN_INCOME_TAX  + ", " + COLUMN_INCOME_NET_PROFIT
            + ", " + COLUMN_INCOME_EARN_PER_SHARE + ") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    public static String getInsertIncomeStatement() {
        return INSERT_INCOME_STATEMENT;
    }
```

I know that it has something to do with the variable assignment statement in the open() method because when I comment it out, the program works just fine and I can connect to the database. I've tried looking at answers from other questions that were similar to mine on here, but any changes I've made to the syntax of the sqlite statement itself still leave me with the same error. I've tried tracing the thread stack to see what "Statement" refers to in the error, but I'm still not sure. Could someone help me pinpoint further where the problem might be?

Here is the trace stack:

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "Statements": syntax error)
    at sqlite.jdbc@3.23.1/org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:909)
    at sqlite.jdbc@3.23.1/org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:921)
    at sqlite.jdbc@3.23.1/org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:886)
    at sqlite.jdbc@3.23.1/org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare_utf8(Native Method)
    at sqlite.jdbc@3.23.1/org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(NativeDB.java:127)
    at sqlite.jdbc@3.23.1/org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(DB.java:227)
    at sqlite.jdbc@3.23.1/org.sqlite.core.CorePreparedStatement.<init>(CorePreparedStatement.java:45)
    at sqlite.jdbc@3.23.1/org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.<init>(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:30)
    at sqlite.jdbc@3.23.1/org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4PreparedStatement.<init>(JDBC4PreparedStatement.java:19)
    at sqlite.jdbc@3.23.1/org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC4Connection.java:48)
    at sqlite.jdbc@3.23.1/org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC3Connection.java:263)
    at sqlite.jdbc@3.23.1/org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC3Connection.java:235)
    at sqlite.jdbc@3.23.1/org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC3Connection.java:242)
    at AccountingFinancialModellingAndValuationApplication/com.anniemals.database.DBManager.open(DBManager.java:60)
    at AccountingFinancialModellingAndValuationApplication/com.anniemals.Main.main(Main.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
```

Thanks in advance to those who can help.

Answer (score 1):

The table name defined by this line:

```
public static final String TABLE_INCOME = "Income Statements"
```

contains a space and this is not allowed.
Change to this:

```
public static final String TABLE_INCOME = "[Income Statements]"
```

When a table or column name contains spaces must be enclosed in square brackets or backticks (ASCII code 096).
You must do the same **for column names containing spaces or dots**:

```
public static final String TABLE_INCOME = "[Income Statements]";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_CLIENT_ID = "[Client ID]";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_DATE = "Date";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_TOTAL_OPER_EXPENSES = "[Total Operating Expenses]";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_GROSS_PROFIT = "[Gross Profit]";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_AMORTIZATION = "Amortization";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_EBITDA = "[E.B.I.T.D.A.]";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_PROFIT_BEFORE_TAX = "[Profit Before Tax]";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_TAX = "Tax";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_NET_PROFIT = "[Net Profit]";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_EARN_PER_SHARE = "[Earnings Per Share]";
```

What seems strange is that since you are trying to insert rows to the table this means that you already created the table. 
But how? 
What names did you use for the table and the columns in the CREATE statement?

Comment: I'm using an application called "DB Browser for Sqlite" to create the tables for me. However, when I checked the database in the app, the table wasn't even created. I created the table and put all values with spaces in brackets like you stated, but I still get the same error.

Comment: I don't have the CREATE statement in my java project. Would I still need the CREATE statement anyway to check and see if the table was created or not through an if statement?

Comment: What is this, an android app?

Comment: Did you create the table in  "DB Browser for Sqlite"?

Comment: It is a desktop app I'm trying to create with JavaFX and JDBC

Comment: Yes, I created the table in "DB Browser for Sqlite"

Comment: If the table is created and the names of the table and columns match the ones in your code and this path: `"jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Steven/Documents/ProjectAnnieMalsRemote/Databases/" + DB_NAME` is correct then you should be able to insert rows.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. It is not the prettiest solution, but it works. Basically, I added a create method to the DBManager class as suggested by forpas:

```
 public boolean checkCreateIncomeStatementTable(){
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Income_Statements(\n" +
            " _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\n" +
            " Client_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,\n" +
            " Date NUMERAL,\n" +
            " Total_Operating_Expenses DOUBLE NOT NULL,\n" +
            " Gross_Profit DOUBLE NOT NULL,\n" +
            " Amortization DOUBLE NOT NULL,\n" +
            " EBITDA DOUBLE NOT NULL,\n" +
            " Profit_Before_Tax DOUBLE NOT NULL,\n" +
            " Tax DOUBLE NOT NULL,\n" +
            " Net_Profit DOUBLE NOT NULL,\n" +
            " Earnings_Per_Share DOUBLE NOT NULL\n" +
            ");";
    try{
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_PATH);
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Database Opened");
        statement.executeQuery(sql);
        System.out.println("Checked creation of Income Statement Table");
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Couldn't connect to database: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, for each column label with spaces in it, I used underscores since the Main class did not want to read brackets for some reason;

```
public static final String TABLE_INCOME = "Income_Statements";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_CLIENT_ID = "Client_ID";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_DATE = "Date";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_TOTAL_OPER_EXPENSES = "Total_Operating_Expenses";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_GROSS_PROFIT = "Gross_Profit";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_AMORTIZATION = "Amortization";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_EBITDA = "EBITDA";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_PROFIT_BEFORE_TAX = "Profit_Before_Tax";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_TAX = "Tax";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_NET_PROFIT = "Net_Profit";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOME_EARN_PER_SHARE = "Earnings_Per_Share";
```

Everything seems to be working now